# yo meanjs app template installation error

Tags: ubuntu, npm, meanjs, yo

am a newbie in meanjs app development so i decided to follow the tutorial at http://www.bradoncode.com/tutorials/mean-stack-tutorial-part-1-setup/

I have installed the necessary tools to get started using the commands below
    sudo npm install -g bower
    sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
    sudo npm install -g yo
    sudo npm install -g generator-meanjs

I have created a project directory,but meanjs app installation always fails at a point with the error below
using both  **yo meanjs** and  **sudo yo meanjs** commands
 . I know it has something to do with root permission, PLEASE HELP ME OUT!

```
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cd mean && npm install.
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-30-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! path /home/omoniyi289/.npm/mongoose/4.2.5
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/omoniyi289/.npm/mongoose/4.2.5'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/omoniyi289/.npm/mongoose/4.2.5']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/omoniyi289/.npm/mongoose/4.2.5',<br>
npm ERR!   parent: 'mean' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/omoniyi289/NorthwindNode/mean/npm-debug.log

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:203:12)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

Comment: Try pasting the command by yourself and add `sudo` to it.

`cd mean && sudo npm install`

Answer (score 1):

please check out this link:
[this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)
from the official npm documentation. Hope it helps.

> Otherwise you could uninstall npm and reinstall with the excellent node version manager(nvm). This alows you to install various versions of node and use whichever at a time. It also allows you to run `npm install` without the sudo prefix.

```
npm install -g nvm
```

update your path to include ./node_modules/.bin

```
 export PATH=./node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

then to install a node version(e.g. 5.0)

```
nvm install 5.0
```

then to use version 5.0

```
nvm use 5.0
```

Comment: Thanks lon!, i followed the first suggestion but still brings same error.  The second suggestion says node 5.0 doesn't exit after installing nvm and trying to download it using nvm!

Comment: check (https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) for node versions. 5.0 is the latest version, but I just used it as an example. I use 0.10.32